# Pyspark rdd.toDF() Data Loss

Tags: pyspark, broadcast

I have an RDD created with a fairly complex mapping function that takes advantage of a large, broadcast dictionary.  If I look at `rdd.filter(lambda x: x... == CONDITION).collect()` to extract a couple cases I've seen that have been representative of my data loss issue, the data is correct and complete.  When I then try `df = rdd.toDF()`, and then `df.where(CONDITION).collect()`, large portions of many elements of the data have been replaced by `None`.

If this gives any hint, the rows/elements are feature sets, and each row is created in blocks, with separate calls to the broadcasted dictionary for each block.  When the data is cast from a number (sometimes all reals, sometimes all zeros, sometimes 1-hot) to None, it seems to always be done over one/some of the complete blocks in which the row/element vector is patched together.

To give a better example of the code

```
def map_fxn(row, n_dim, dict_bc, row_constr):
  if row['key'] in dict_bc.value:
    rvec = dict_bc.value[row['key']
  else:
    rvec = [0] * n_dim
  return row_constr(row['id'], *rvec)

my_dict = {'key1' : range(10,20), 'key2' : range(20,30)}
n_dim = 10
dict_bc = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(my_dict)
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([Row(key='key1', id='id1'), 
                                      Row(key='key3', id='id3')])
row_constr = Row('id', *['val' + str(i) for i in range(n_dim)])
rdd_map = rdd.map(lambda x: map_fxn(x, n_dim, dict_bc, row_constr)
df = rdd_map.toDF()
```

Then `rdd_map` is fine.  `df` has random seeming rows with `None` values instead of either 0s or the values from `dict_bc.value`.  The dictionary is loaded from S3 output of mllib, where every entry is guaranteed to be a double.  So there are no strings anywhere.  I've tried casting the RDD to a DF using the `createDataFrame` function both from `SparkSession` and from `SQLContext`, with a schema built manually.  Both return fine but then error out with unhelpful, failed n times, error messages if you try to actually do anything at all with the dataframe.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. Almost surely this is due to a type mismatch, but impossible to tell without seeing a representative example of your data.

Comment: Added some code that gives an idea of what I'm trying to do